# system_auth replication in Cassandra

Tags: spring, authentication, cassandra, replication, scalability

I'm trying to configure authentication on Cassandra. It seems like because of replication strategy that is used for system_auth, it can't replicate user credentials to all the nodes in cluster, so I end up getting Incorrect credentials on one node, and getting successful connection on another.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25891353/replication-factor-to-use-for-system-auth) is related question. The guy there says you have to make sure credentials are always on all nodes.

How to do it? The option that is offered there says you have to alter keyspace to put replication factor equal to amount of nodes in cluster, then run repair on each node. That's whole tons of work to be done if you want your cassandra to be dynamically scalable. If I add 1 node today, 1 node another day, alter keyspace replication and then keep restarting nodes manually that will end up some kind of chaos.

Hour of googling actually leaded to slightly mentioned [EverywhereStrategy](http://www.cassadmin.com/2015/10/configuring-authentication-in-cassandra.html), but I don't see anywhere in docs it mentioned as available. How do people configure APIs to work with Cassandra authentication then, if you can't be sure that your user actually present on node, that you're specifying as contact point?

Obviously, talking about true scale, when you can change the size of cluster without doing restarts of each node.

Comment: Why do you think that you have to restart your node?

Comment: It still not letting me to login after alter&repair. Only restart of node makes the change applied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you enable authentication in Cassandra, then **Yes** you have increase the system_auth keyspace replication_factor to N(total number of nodes) and run a complete repair, but you don't need to restart the nodes after you add a new Node.

If repair is consuming more time then you optimize your repair like repair only the system_auth keyspace

```
nodetool repair system_auth
```

(or)

```
nodetool repair -pr system_auth
```

As per Cassandra a complete repair should be done regularly. For more details on repair see the below links:

http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/repair-in-cassandra

https://www.pythian.com/blog/effective-anti-entropy-repair-cassandra/

http://docs.datastax.com/en/archived/cassandra/2.2/cassandra/tools/toolsRepair.html

Answering your questions:

**Question:** How do people configure APIs to work with Cassandra authentication then, if you can't be sure that your user actually present on node, that you're specifying as contact point?

**Answer:** I'm using Cassandra 2.2 and Astyanax thrift API from my Spring project, using which I am able to handle the Cassandra authentication effectively. Specify what version of Cassandra you are using and what driver you are using to connect CQL driver or Astyanax thrift API?

**Question:** Obviously, talking about true scale, when you can change the size of cluster without doing restarts of each node.

**Answer:** Yes you can scale your Cassandra cluster without restarting nodes, please check the datastax documentation for Cassandra 2.2 version:
http://docs.datastax.com/en/archived/cassandra/2.2/cassandra/operations/opsAddNodeToCluster.html

Check the datastax docs for the version you are using.

Comment: Repair not letting me connect to new node till I actually restart it. COSS 3.9 is my distributive. Considering api - I tried basic cqlsh. Rescaling cluster is not a problem for me, rather actually being able to create new contact point accessible for new API server via user credentials. For time being I use "consistency all" and recreating users when adding new nodes.

Comment: Using consistency all will make the coordinator node to respond after all replicas have responded to it. The operation will fail if any one replica does not respond. So it might be the reason for not connecting to the new node. Try using QUORUM level consistency, to know more about the consistency levels take a look at http://docs.datastax.com/en/archived/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/dml/dml_config_consistency_c.html

Comment: Good point, thanks. That however doesn't solve the problem, seem more of a hack :(

Comment: When you added a new node, did it joined the cluster? you can check this using nodetool status, If the new node didnot join the cluster then there might be some issue with configurations in cassandra.yaml file, can you share your seeds and endpoint snitch configurations of your nodes

Comment: The way I checked is my cluster already had 4 nodes, but replication factor was set to 3. I altered system_auth replication factor to 4, repaired every node, but the last 4th node catched the change only when I restarted it. Does the sync take place only during new connection?

Comment: Ok, when you increase replication factor then you need the data to be replicated as set in the replication factor, So try doing **nodetool rebuild** after increasing the replication factor. Here are some post which might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17602125/cassandra-node-rebuild-v-s-repair